# custom css files for drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to implement a drop down as show in the following figure. I am trying to use html, css and bootstrap. Could someone please help me in figuring out, how to write the css code in order to get such a drop down list.

Is it possible to achieve this using html and css or do we need a third party plugin?

[image: Drop Down]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is posible, have a look to this link http://www.kevinfremon.com/create-a-custom-drop-down-list-using-just-css/

Answer (score 0):

The options part can't be customised using css. In that case you'd need to use a third party library and there are plenty out there (eg: [MUI](https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/css-js/dropdowns))

[image]

Else the [link](http://www.kevinfremon.com/create-a-custom-drop-down-list-using-just-css/) suggested by kraiosis is perfect